# Unity Shader: Make water on terrain transparent without fading

Tags: unity, shaders, terrain

I want to create a shader for a terrain to make the water fully transparent but not invisible or faded.

In this example I would want the purple square to be seen through water but not through the land.
[image]

I want the water to look exactly the same as before.

I want objects underneath the terrain to be visible through the water.

I already have a shader to make objects underneath the water look like they are seen through water.

I want to use a single camera as I would need a slow script on each of the cameras.

Comment: Can you show us what your water shader looks like currently? And in particular, what it looks like when there's something under it?